# Given two functions how can I calculate for which N does one become greater than the other one?

Tags: functions

For example we have two functions $f(n)=8n^2$ and $g(n)=64n\log_2n$. If $n=2$ then $f(2)=32$ and $g(2)=128$. At one point $f(n)$ will become greater then $g(n)$. How can I calculate the exact $n$ after which that happens?

Comment: *Welcome to the site !* Are the $n$'s supposed to be $x$'s ?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, thanks for pointing that out, I will edit it.

Comment: Can you use calculus? Otherwise the resulting inequality is going to be tough...

Comment: Yes, and to make it even more simple you can assume that n is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

SImplifying the problem, you are looking for the zero of function
$$f(n)=n-8\log_2(n)$$
the solution of which (in the real domain) being given in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)
$$n=-\frac{8 }{\ln (2)}W_{-1}\left(-\frac{\ln (2)}{8}\right)\approx 43.5593 \implies n \geq 44$$